# How to break one integer value into multiple integer values

Tags: php, arrays, integer

I need to break an integer value into 2 or more integer values.

Example Input: `$total_marks = 42`

Output:

```
$sub1 = 20;
$sub2 = 22;
```

Condition: `$total_marks = $sub1 + $sub2;`

thanks

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see **[How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)** and **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39931925/edit) the post to add relevant code in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [divisors of divisors of a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071307/divisors-of-divisors-of-a-number)

Comment: Is there ANY rationale for dividing 42 into THESE values?

Comment: It seems a very random algorithm! Please add some details! Is there any input? Will it be always 5 numbers to divide?

Comment: No. It will change based on number of subject.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,it will work for even and odd marks.

```
$total_marks = 42;
if(($total_marks%2) == 0)
{
    $num1 = $total_marks/2;
    $num2 = $num1;
    echo $num1 ." AND ".$num2." sum is ".$total_marks ;
}else
{
    $num1 = $total_marks/2; 
    $num1 = floor($num1);
    $num2 = $num1  + 1;

    echo $num1 ." AND ".$num2." sum is ".$total_marks ;
}
```